# how to increase msgmax from 8192-bytes ( /proc/sys/kernel/msgmax) to 16000

Tags: linux, ipc

We are using message queue IPC mechanism in our project.

But our message size is approx: 15000 bytes.

How to increase msgmax( /proc/sys/kernel/msgmax) from default value 8192 to 15000?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can set msgmax with the following command (as root):

`sysctl -w kernel.msgmax=16384`